# Fundamentals: The role of battery in a circuit

Tags: batteries, charge

- As I understood, the analogy of a charge moving through a circuit is similar to water flowing from a high altitude to a low altitude (like waterfalls).
- But in waterfalls there are two requirements if we wanted to keep that same water repeating the cycle, we need a gravitational field, which is caused by the earth, and an energy supplier that will do work on water to move it from the low altitude (low gravitational potential) to high altitude (high gravitational potential).
- In circuits, I do understand that the battery does the part of moving a positive charge from a low potential energy point (the negative terminal) to the high one (the positive terminal) so it can -again- move to the negative terminal naturally.
- But for that movement to occur (moving in the external circuit) we need an E field (in analogy of the waterfall we need earth to establish its gravitational field), so the battery should establish an E field, and give energy to charges in the wires to "re-climb" to higher potential energy points relative to that field?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118964/discussion-on-question-by-jalaleddin-el-firqi-fundamentals-the-role-of-battery).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the charge carriers (electrons) are „elevated“ inside the battery to a higher potential. From there they can flow back through the wire to the lower potential where they came from originally.